# Delete blog post older than 30 days Automatically

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to Automatically delete blog post that are older than 30 days in my Django project. I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: Look up Celery for Django.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple.

Create a management command and call it every month with crontab.

**Crontab** - https://tecadmin.net/crontab-in-linux-with-20-examples-of-cron-schedule/

**Management command Django** - https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/08/27/how-to-create-custom-django-management-commands.html

```py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Delete blog post'

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Do stuff here - Delete posts
```

Crontab

```
0 0 * * *  python /path/to/manage.py mycommand
```

Comment: Better call it once a day and delete those posts that are older than a month. Besides, `timezone` is not required to create a command (it is a copy/paste from link).